# Resolving rtmp stream url from Adobe Flash container

Tags: ffmpeg, flash, live-streaming

How can a rtmp stream url be retrieved completely with its playpath and be played with ffplay/avconv from a flash plugin. In embedded flash code below rtmp address exits (rtmp://live.atv.com.tr/atv) , however it does not work with avplay since it needs playpath.

```
<param value="config={"key":"#@c67bf4e753034f78950","play":{"display":"none"},"clip":{"eventCategory":"Canli Yayin","url":"atv3","live":true,"provider":"influxis"},"plugins":{"controls":{"url":"http://i.tmgrup.com.tr/p/flowplayer.controls.swf"},"influxis":{"url":"http://i.tmgrup.com.tr/p/flowplayer.rtmp.swf","netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://live.atv.com.tr/atv"},"ova":{"url":"http://i.tmgrup.com.tr/p/ova.swf","autoPlay":true,"overlays":{"regions":[{"id":"Reklam","verticalAlign":"bottom","horizontalAlign":"right","backgroundC...0,"style":".smalltext { font-style: italic; font-size:10; }"}]},"ads":{"notice":{"show":true,"region":"my-ad-notice","message":"<p class=\"smalltext\" align=\"right\"> Kalan süre : _countdown_ saniye.</p>"},"schedule":[{"zone":"5","position":"pre-roll","server":{"type":"direct","apiAddress":"http%3a%2f%2fad.reklamport.com%2frpgetad.ashx%3ftt%3dt_atv_canli_yayin_preroll_800x700%26vast%3d2"}}]}}},"playerId":"live","playlist":[{"eventCategory":"Canli Yayin","url":"atv3","live":true,"provider":"influxis"}]}" name="flashvars">
```

Problem Solved: Using wireshark (network analyzer) is much more effective to retrieve paramaters like rtmp url, playpath... 
Edit2: Some urls are also embedded in scripts files rather than directly in flash object, this variables are used in flash object above, later.